# button:active styling issues on safari

Tags: css, button, safari

Came across an issue where button text was 'disappering' when we long press on the button on safari.

To give context , the button is styled as below

```
button{
border:1px solid #ccc;
background-color:#FFF;
padding:5px;
}
```

Pretty straightforward and uneventful . But when one long presses the button on safari the color of the text changes to  `activebuttontext`.

Note that this doesnt happen when you explicitly set a color to the button like so

```
 button{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:red
    padding:5px;
    }
```

jsfiddle is given here to reproduce the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/402Lrj7x/8/

Also this doesn't happen on other webkit based browsers like Chrome.

Long story short,What is this `color:activebuttontext` ? how is it derived ?

*P.S:Not looking for a fix, as the fix is straightforward .*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after running around the Safari source code in git , was able to understand that they are using `activebuttontext` as a variable of sorts to apply "#FFF" color as required.

The line in question can be seen here in the [webkit repository](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/a1332878223ea9cc4738676e7db8d2762b71c4f6/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderTheme.cpp#L1260)

```
case CSSValueActivebuttontext:
        return 0xFF000000;
```

This in turn gets applied as User Agent style sheet to the `button` element.